# "Select data source" popping-up when executing a SQL writed query

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I try to create a pretty complex database on ms Access 2013, so I wanted to type it directly in SQL. It has no errors, as other DBMS can fully build the database from the script I wrote (for example, phpmyadmin imports it with no difficulty).

On [this tutorial](http://www.addictivetips.com/microsoft-office/create-tables-in-access-2010-using-sql-commands/), it is showed how to write a SQL query in order to build tables. I thought this way matched well with my goal as I could copy-paste my script in the query and run it to create the whole thing.

But when I tried to open/double-click on the query a pop-up appears saying "Select data source", waiting for me to select an ODBC, either from a file or a host, before continuing and executing the query.

I tried other types of queries (creating only one table at time, trying on a blank file, or even `SELECT * FROM *`), bt this message keeps showing up and I really don't know how to deal with it as I don't want to connect to anything but the infile database.

Does anyone got a hint about what to do in this case?
Or, even better, how could Access import my SQL script in order to create the database?

Comment: Do you have a DB server you want to connect to, or do you want to create the tables in the local Access database? If it's Access, perhaps you have created a Pass-Through query by mistake?

Comment: You really need to study a general tutorial in Access and how ODBC connections are (supposed to be) used.

Comment: The long term goal is to create a local Access DB.
/// If so, Gustav, could you advise me a good tutorial, I've tried to help myself about ODBC but I still can't handle the connection manager...

Answer (score 0):

You should configure the database connection in the ODBC and check whether the connection is established or not. Once the connection is established, you can run the query to fetch the data or create tables as per your requirement.